# using Fail-fast approach when developing modular applications

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, error-handling, modularity

When developing modular applications is it quiet obvious that we need to use [Fail-fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) systems?

When creating modules if there is an error condition the module cannot handle, it should report the error(like throw an exception..)without worrying who will handle it. It looks like this can be used as a guideline when developing modules. Is there any issues with this?

**Edit**:Example

**In module.dll**

```
public class SomeClass:ISomeInterface
{

    public void CreateFile(string filename)
    {
       //The module have no idea who calls this. But there is something wrong        
       //somewhere so  throw an exception early. The module writer has no control over 
       //how the exception is handled. So if this exception is not handled by the 
       //Client Application the application can potentially crash.Do he need to worry 
       //about that?
       if(filename == null)
       {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("Filename is null");
       }

       //I think the following is bad. This code is making sure that a module 
       //exception wont crash the application.Is it good?
       //if(filename ==null)
       //{
       //Logger.log("filename is null");
       //return;
       //}
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two categories of critical exceptions I can see: those in which the entire system may have been compromised, and there's not really much that one can safely assume wasn't, and those in which a significant aspect of the system which code is going to expect to "just work", won't, but there's no reason to believe other parts of the system are compromised.  In the former case, there's not really much the program can do except die, possibly trying to log what happened if it can do so without corrupting any "main-line" data.  In the latter case, though, killing the application would be unduly "rude".  A better approach would IMHO be to design the subsystem so that code can "pull the plug" on it to prevent it from causing data corruption, with the consequence that any further attempt to use it (other than an "are you still working" query, whose return value should indicate the problem) will likely throw an immediate exception, but allow those parts of the program that don't need the troubled subsystem to keep running as they were unless or until they decide that there isn't much for them to do without it.

Comment: +1, interesting. What I need to know if there is any way to kill the troubled subsystem? For our application we have different GUI Designers for XML files according to types. These GUI designers are created as modules(subsystems). If becasue of any reason the designer cannot work I want that particular designer to go out of the way of the application, letting rest of the system to work as expected. But the question here is how can the subsystem die in case of an error it cannot handle?

Comment: @Jimmy: One approach is to have a master `IsAlive` property (possibly backed by an `_IsAlive` variable), and have methods which are going to use the object test that variable.  Another approach (which can also be used with the `IsAlive`) is to invalidate fields which the subsystem's methods are going to use, possibly nulling them out or possibly replacing them with references to dummy objects which will throw more informative exceptions when an attempt is made to use them.  For data structures guarded by locks, it may be useful to wrap the locks in a guard which includes a "danger" flag and...

Comment: @Jimmy: ...have code which is going to (hopefully temporarily) violate the invariant which is supposed to hold whenever the lock is released set the danger flag before violating the invariant, and clear it when the invariant is restored.  Calling `Dispose` on the lock guard while the danger flag is set should invalidate the underlying data structure and then clear the lock; thus, other code wanting to use the data structure won't get stuck forever waiting for a lock that will never be released, but won't get to access corrupt data either.

Answer (score 1):

> A fail-fast module passes the responsibility for handling errors, but not detecting them, to the **next-higher system design level**.

From the Wikipedia definition.  What exactly *is* the 'next-higher system design level'.  Should that not be at least a level that reports the failure so somebody can take corrective measures and fix the problem?  Either implemented in a upper layer supplied by the client code that uses your classes.  Or a generic error reporter that gets invoked through AppDomain.UnhandledException.  Both entirely out of your control.

Throw an exception.

Comment: There is a segfault/AV and the stack above has been corrupted.  You gonna risk unwinding it? <g>

Comment: Hmya, you are going to risk reporting it?

Comment: +1, In most of the cases the module wont know what caused the error. It is almost impossible to report the error in this situation. I agree, throw the exception and don't worry about who handles it. By the way, I have a hard time people agree to this.

Comment: @HansPassant - reporting means making more stack. Unwinding means trying to use exiting stack.  The risks are not the same.  I'm not against exceptions for 'file not found' or 'socket closed', but for 'segfault/AV', it may be better to not go back to stuff that may be dead already.  I accept that, in most cases an exception handler a couple of levels up will 'safely' get an AV exception from down below, but it's not guaranteed.  Maybe do both - append the e.message to 'CriticalError.txt' then re-throw.

Comment: An AV just doesn't need any help getting raised, Windows already takes care of it.  Just don't try to help.

Comment: What you posted is fine.  Getting a null argument is a programming bug, whomever wrote the code is quickly going to find the bug with the diagnostic you generate.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when in C++ generally I implement a critical error scheme, I don't let such critical exceptions even leave the exception handler - I call a 'criticalExit()' method of a globally-accessible class instance, (I usually have one of these to store 'global' methods etc, eg. loggers, object pools), with the exception and a string, (string often just the module and function name). criticalExit() locks a mutex, raises its priority to 'THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL', opens a 'CriticalError.Log', appends the exception message and string to the file, closes it and calls ExitProcess(1), (Environment.Exit(1)).

..and, just to see, I've tried doing this in C#.  It's not so easy to generate a globally-accessible single instance :(

Comment: "Modular" system is the catchword. The reason why asked this question is this scenario is almost an "one size fits all" case(if the modules are really designed to work independently). Each module is only concerned with its own duties. If an application uses a modules it is the applications responsibility to glue the modules together and handle errors.

Comment: The situation explained in the answer is in a monolithic application(is it?), I am talking about modules

Comment: A module is a logical collection of code within an Assembly.  It's not unreasonable for one C# module to be 'CriticalErrorHandler' and to be called from other modules.